# Two floating elements' margin affected by adjacent element's margin

Tags: html, css

The margin of the two floating images changes as I modify the margin of an adjacent nav bar. Why does this occcur? http://jsfiddle.net/cuzox/waPr4/1/

```
*HTML*
<div>
    <div id="no1">Image</div>
    <div id="no2">Image</div>
    <div id="no3">Nav</div>
</div>

*CSS*
#no1{
width:100px;
height:100px;
float:left;
background-color:#A1A1A1;
}

#no2{
width:100px;
height:100px;
float:left;    
background-color:#B1B1B1;
}

#no3{
margin-top:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you add `float:left;` to `#no3` the `#no3` element does not respect the other two elements, and therefore is contained in the full width of the container. Causing the other two element to be affected when margins are added to the `#no3` element.

Comment: This looks so obvious now but it sure gave me a headache. Thanks man!

Comment: No problem :) could you please accept it as the best answer please if it worked

Comment: I didn't know how to do that xD